# Passing value from text input into javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield

Inside my html file I call a javascript function that takes two parameters, where the second parameter is the name of a file that should be saved.

```
<a id="record_button" onclick="Recorder.record('audio', 'test.wav');" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Record"><img src="images/record.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Record"/></a>
```

I would like to make a dynamic variable that takes the value from a textfield and forward that as the second parameter (instead of test.wav), so the user can determine the name of the file.

```
<label for="filename">Filename</label>
<input name="filename" type="text">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easier if you give your user input an `id` attribute:

```
<input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">
```

Now you can access the value in Javascript with:

```
document.getElementById('filename').value
```

Note that, if you aren't controlling the `Recorder.record()` method, you'll need to validate the user input first (at a minimum, to verify that they've entered something). I'd recommend moving this to a separate function, e.g.:

```
function recordToFilename() {
    var input = document.getElementById('filename'),
        fileName = input.value;
    if (fileName) {
        Recorder.record('audio', fileName);
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a filename!');
        input.focus();
    }
}
```

Then just use that function:

```
<a id="record_button" onclick="recordToFilename();" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Record"><img src="images/record.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Record"/></a>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/GFpRy/

Comment: Good one. Just add a `fileName.focus()` below to `alert` :)

Comment: @Márcio - good idea - added above. You could also just make the `alert` a `prompt` and maybe ditch the input altogether...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created a <script>record to filename function</script> inside my HTML file, and to exactly as you have written. However nothing occurs when I press the record button. As soon as I change the onclick to Recorder.record('audio', 'test.wav'); it works, but when changing to recordToFilename(); it doesn't

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors? How are you defining the function? See the working example I included above.

Answer (score 2):

```
Recorder.record('audio', document.yourformname.filename.value)
```

Make sure to have a `name="?"` attribute for your form for this to work and replace `yourformname` with what you put as the form's name. `filename` refers to the input's `name` attribute as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
     function addData (fn, ln, em) {

       console.log(fn);
       console.log(ln);
       console.log(em);

     }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input Type="text" name="FirstName" id="fn">
    <input Type="text" name="LastName" id="ln">
    <input Type="email" name="Email" id="em">
    <button onClick="addData(fn.value,ln.value,em.value)">click</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: when javascript code is fix but html field id is change then we can use this code.

Comment: I can work it out, but I doubt the OP can if they had little experience (although after 6 years of JavaScript he probably should be able to).